# Google Play store App download counter not inreasing even my download 100+ in google analytics?

Tags: android

i uploaded my app on Google play store 2 days before and i also link my app with google analytic it shows download counter 119 in Google analytic, but in Google play store it shows 0+ dowloads. please help me..

Comment: This is not something you yourself can influence. This has to do with when the google server update their statistics for each app. May be daily, weekly, monthly. But nothing anyone here can do will influence it I think..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statistics shown in the developer console are supposed to be updated daily, but I have had delays of 48 hours or more before. The Analytics numbers are more accurate.